# How to write my own filter for predecessors in VBA for MS Project?

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I am currently setting up a GAANT chart to determine the runtime and dependencies of a huge project.

There are a little over 600 tasks. They are dependent on each other, but unfortunately not in a linear and clustered way.

I can colourise the predecessors and successors of one task. But, because there are other tasks in between, I need to scroll a lot to get to the next connected task.

I want to write a filter in VBA, so that it will show me ONLY the connected Predecessors and Successors of the selected task.

So far I do not even know how to write a simple filter, because the online documentation is very poor, when it comes to filters.

Applying a normal filter does not work, because it will give me only the direct predecessors and successors.

I expect the predecessors of the predecessor, and so on.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of google. It is a bit of a workaround.

My code flags all the predecessors with a simple "Yes" in the Projects Field "Text10" (you can use any other Text field), and then I filter all the tasks with the "Yes".

```
Dim ProjTasks As Tasks
Dim ProjTasks2 As Task
Dim ProjTasks3 As Tasks
Dim ProjTask As Task
Dim ProjTask2 As Task
Dim ProjTask3 As Task

Dim Deadline As String

Set ProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks
Set ProjTasks2 = ActiveProject.Tasks
Set ProjTasks3 = ActiveProject.Tasks
```

So here comes the main part of my code:

```
 For Each ProjTask In ProjTasks
        If ProjTask.Start < (DateValue(Deadline) + TimeValue(Deadline)) Then
            For Each ProjTask2 In ProjTasks2
                If ProjTask2.Start < (DateValue(Deadline) + TimeValue(Deadline)) Then
                If Not (ProjTask2 Is Nothing) Then
                    If ProjTask2.Text10 = "YES" Then
                        PredArray() = Split(ProjTask2.Predecessors, ";")
                        For Each i In PredArray()
                            For Each ProjTask3 In ProjTasks3
                                If ProjTask3.Start < (DateValue(Deadline) + TimeValue(Deadline)) Then
                                If ProjTask3.ID = i Then
                                    ProjTask3.Text10 = "YES"
                                End If
                                End If
                            Next ProjTask3
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
                End If
            Next ProjTask2
        End If
    Next ProjTask
```

Because it contains 3 `for-loops` I tried to minimise the number of tasks, that are looped over.

Because I can see when my target task ends (`Deadline`), I do not loop over tasks which have a beginning time after the end time of my target task.

Be careful, that code takes some time to run through. After the code ran through, you can go to column "Text10" and filter the "Yes".

Comment: FYI: this code will fail if any task links contain lags, non-FS link types, or links to external projects. These scenarios are very common in large schedules. Better to use the PredecessorTasks and SuccessorTasks properties than to try and split the Predecessors and Successors fields.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MS Project 2013, there is a feature that *highlights* Predecessors and Successors of the active task (see end for details).

However, to hide all tasks not linked to a particular task requires code. Fortunately the [PredecessorTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.predecessortasks) and [SuccessorTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.successortasks) collection objects make easy work of this.

This code finds all tasks linked to the target task (active task in this case) and sets a flag (Text10='Yes') so that non-linked tasks can be filtered out. The code only touches tasks linked to the target task, and only touches them one time each so it runs very quickly.

The code can be easily modified to use a different target task and to add criteria such as to skip over completed tasks.

```
Sub FlagTasksLinkedtoTargetTask()

    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        tsk.Text10 = vbNullString
    Next tsk

    Dim TargetTask As Task
    Set TargetTask = Application.ActiveCell.Task

    FlagPredecessors TargetTask
    FlagSuccessors TargetTask

End Sub

Sub FlagPredecessors(tsk As Task)

    Dim pred As Task
    For Each pred In tsk.PredecessorTasks
        If pred.Text10 <> "Yes" Then
            pred.Text10 = "Yes"
            FlagPredecessors pred
        End If
    Next pred

End Sub

Sub FlagSuccessors(tsk As Task)

    Dim succ As Task
    For Each succ In tsk.SuccessorTasks
        If succ.Text10 <> "Yes" Then
            succ.Text10 = "Yes"
            FlagSuccessors succ
        End If
    Next succ

End Sub
```

FYI: The highlighting feature is found under Task Path on the Format tab (when viewing a Gantt Chart view). You can select to highlight Predecessors, Driving Predecessors (only the ones that currently are affecting the date), Successors, and/or Driven Successors. Here's the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-how-tasks-link-to-other-tasks-afad334a-6051-4b18-acdb-73b63a651b4d).

Comment: Hi Rachel, that is not what I am looking for. Your solution only highlights the predecessors and successors. But I want to filter out all tasks, that are not linked (in any way) to my task.

Comment: @Peter, no problem. Most times when people want to see the predecessors/successors, this highlighting feature works great. I updated the answer to provide a fast, robust solution to filtering out all tasks not linked to a given task.